# Array count including unset items?

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to get an array count after items have been unset from the array and include the unset items in the count?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: no, I don't believe you can get them after they are unset, before yes, after very unlikely.  Unset doesn't just hide them it initiates garbage collection on them, ie they no longer exist.

Comment: Weird request. Couldn't you just keep a variable copy of the array that you're unsetting on, then count the copy when you need to count?

Comment: 1) You can also keep the count of unsetting items and and add to the total count of array items. 2) Also, instead to unsetting array item you can set its value to null, after this if you take the count of the array you will get total count of array including null